# Ignore Phone's Dial Pad if user clicks text containing numbers

Tags: php, android, iphone, html

I'm developing a web application to track inventory. Almost done. Just noticed one problem when testing on my phone.

If a user is on his/her phone and selects a part/serial number it brings up the dial pad for the phone.

Is there a tag I could wrap around these to get the phone(s) to ignore their dialpad and treat it as a click.. Other than making them all link's pointing back to the page (#) they are on I've yet to find a way around it.

Anyone have any input? Because this is really annoying and the whole reason I developed this application was so we could use it on our phones out in the field.

Google / StackOverflow Queries returned 0 useful results.

Answer (score 1):

In your site's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```